# android.os.FileUriExposedException Error - XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to do the file picker thing, and it works with lower SDK versions but in this case (android 7.1) it requires the FileProvider.

The thing is that I have seen a lot of answers on the internet and I think that's all OK with my code. What do you think? Why can't I find the reference to the FileProvider in my class?

Hope someone has the idea why this is not working for me, here is the code:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.AppQ4evo" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="AppQ4evo.Android" android:icon="@drawable/srw_circular">
    <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.companyname.AppQ4evo.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Resources/xml/filepaths.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**EDIT1(The Error):**

[image]

Comment: When you say file picker what exactly are you trying to pick here?

Comment: In this case its a pdf, but it works on android 4.4 for exemple, but in android 7.1 it does not.

Comment: So basically it throws an exception on Android 7.1 and if it does can i look at the exception stack trace?

Comment: I edit the post and post the error on the android device @G.hakim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was not easy to find out, but it look's like I need to add-in this extention:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings#qna

By add-in this you can now add references to the android directly like, and-in references from java(In my case **FileProvider**).

The tutorial for this is right in this link at github:

https://github.com/EgorBo/Xamarin.GradleBindings

Hope it helps people with this problem.